# como puedo moverme a otro componente al presionar un boton en next.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, next.js

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion web usando Next.js, pero estoy teniendo problemas al querer moverme a otro componente al presionar un boton, donde el codigo lo tengo estructurado de la siguiente manera:

[image: Estructura del proyecto]

donde el page.tsx es mi componente principal donde tengo dividido el código en tres secciones como se muestra en la siguiente imagen:

[image: división de la pagina]

tomando como ejemplo el componente Hero, su carpeta tiene 3 archivos, uno es el css, el otro el componente y un index.ts el cual es la dirección con el que lo mandaba a llamar para hacer la división de la pagina web en 3 secciones, lo unico de codigo que tiene el index.ts es esto:

```
export {Hero} from './Hero';
```

básicamente es el mismo código para casa index.ts de cada componente solo cambia el nombre y dirección.
Ahora viene mi gran problema, en el componente Hero.tsx que es la parte superior de la pagina tengo dos botones , uno para login y otro para registrarse y quiero que cuando le de click a uno me redireccione al componente  tomando como ejemplo el componente Login.tsx que esta estructurado igual que los otros componentes, pero hasta ahora no he logrado hacer que me redireccione, estos son los ejemplos del codigo

ejemplo de como esta el boton:

```
           <button onClick={btnLogin} className={style.button}>
            <div>
                <span>
                    <p>Login</p><p>:)</p>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>
                    <p>:D</p>
                </span>
            </div>
        </button>
```

y este es el ejemplo de como estan los onclick :

```
  "use client"
   import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
   import style from './Hero.module.css'

   export const Hero = () => {
   const router = useRouter();


function btnRegister() {

}

function btnLogin() {

}
```

aqui vuelvo a dejar como esta estructurado las carpetas:

[image: estructura carpetas]

Pido una disculpa si tengo muchas malas practicas, aun sigo aprendiendo a usar next.js y es una tarea de universidad así que no tengo problemas con que se muestre el contenido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para empezar un componente es una función que permite separar interfaces en piezas independientes y reutilizables. Si quieres visualizar algunos de estos mediante eventos puedes hacerlo manejando estados en la aplicación la cual no sería la mejor opción en tu caso. Observando la estructura del código doy por echo que estas utilizando `App Router`.

lo que puedes hacer es crear dos carpetas dentro de app y llamarlas `register` y `login` que serían el nombre de las rutas. Dentro de estas crear un archivo llamado `page.tsx` donde escribirás la estructura de la autenticación.

Una vez hecho esto ya tendrás creada dos rutas `/login` y `/register` cuya interfaz principal es `page.tsx`.

Para redireccionar harias lo siguiente:

```
"use client"


import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import style from './Hero.module.css'

export const Hero = () => {
const router = useRouter();


function btnRegister() {
   router.push('/register')
}

function btnLogin() {
    router.push('/login')
}
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco demasiado, me ayudaste a resolver ese problema de una manera sencilla y clara.